# Pulling Org structure out of AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

is there a way to pull an employee's org structure out of Azure AD? I don't see any graph API for it, so may have to do recursive calls until I reach the top???.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does exist, you can use the [List manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method, you'll have to traverse through the hierarchy though to build out your organisational chart, you cannot build one automatically using the API.